# Dual OS (win10/Ubuntu) boot problem

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, monitors, high-dpi

I have installed dual OS Win10/Ubuntu, but I have some boot problems. My computer has a Nvidia GPU with a high refresh rate (144Hz) monitor. The monitor has DP 1.4/HDMI 2.1/Type-C interfaces. I first used DP cable, but when I boot the grub does not appear and it enters Ubuntu directly.

Then I also connected the monitor's HDMI to the VGA interface on the motherboard (via an adaptor). Now two cables are connected to the monitor and I can switch between DP and HDMI. When I reboot and switch the input to HDMI, the grub can appear in general, if I choose Windows the monitor does not show the graphical interface, but I believe it has entered the Windows OS since the keyboard light is on and the monitor is not really black but with a luminance background. When I reboot and switch the input to DP, the grub does not appear and it enters Ubuntu again.

My questions are:

1. Why is GRUB not displayed when I use the DP interface, and Ubuntu starts automatically?
2. Why does GRUB show up when I use the HDMI interface, but the monitor does not show a graphical interface if I choose Windows?
3. What should I do to make the grub displayed if I use the DP interface (because it supports a high refresh rate) to allow me to choose which OS to start? Someone else told me this problem has something to do with the high refresh rate (144Hz) monitor.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: `Why is GRUB not loading when I use the DP interface, and Ubuntu starts automatically?` It really just sounds like grub is not *displayed* and after its boot menu timeout, it boots the default entry which is Ubuntu. It might not have anything to do with grub or the refresh rate, because as per your description, you seem to have your iGPU enabled while you have a display card. Often in this case pre-OS display only shows up on screen connected to a motherboard's port.

Comment: @TomYan Yes, I meant grub is not displayed and Ubuntu starts automatically when I use the DP interface. Because only when I enabled the integrated GPU, grub can display. If I disable it and use the display card with the DP cable, grub will not show up.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a BIOS setting that allows you to choose the GPU that is activated first at boot time. If such setting is available, it often defaults to the motherboard's iGPU. Changing that setting might help.

Also, NVidia has recently released a DisplayPort firmware update for some GPU models:

- https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nv-uefi-update-x64/ for the GeForce 10, 9 and 7 series (there used to be an earlier similar update for these; this is a new version as of June 2023)
- [https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5233/~/nvidia-gpu-firmware-update-tool-for-displayid](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5233/%7E/nvidia-gpu-firmware-update-tool-for-displayid) for the RTX 30 series

If your GPU is applicable for one of these updates, it seems it might well fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I will try and give feedback later. Is the first update for DP port?

Comment: If you visit the link, you'll see the first update is titled "NVIDIA Graphics Firmware Update Tool for DisplayPort 1.3 and 1.4 Displays". So yes.